# Jquery how to turn .off() to .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have `Jquery` click event and i want to prevent multiple `click` before executing my function `UpdateItemStatus(this.id);`, so i have tried below code using on/off event,

```
$('#tableItems').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
if ($(e.target).closest("td").hasClass("cssClick")) {
    $(this).off(e);
    UpdateItemStatus(this.id);
    $(this).on(e);
}
});
```

but how do i turn .`on`? as it's not working, not able to click again.

Comment: on and off take as parameter the name of the event type, string

Comment: @DhavalMarthak he wants to enable it again after the update has happened

Comment: i need to stop click only during the function execution

Comment: try reading the documentation. Without a handler your attempts are worthless and are likely also throwing errors

Comment: does `UpdateItemStatus` have an asynchronous implementation like a ajax request

Comment: yes, `UpdateItemStatus` has ajax post request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about having a global variable which decides the button click action?

Something like this?

```
var clickevent = true;
$('#tableItems').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    if(clickevent){
        if ($(e.target).closest("td").hasClass("cssClick")) {
            clickevent = false;
            UpdateItemStatus(this.id);
            clickevent = true;
        }
    }
});
```

if `UpdateItemStatus` function has ajax then i recommend you to put `clickevent = true` inside success of that ajax

Comment: thanks for recommend to put `clickevent = true` inside success of ajax

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use off() for your code. Use return false:

```
$('#tableItems').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
if ($(e.target).closest("td").hasClass("cssClick")) {
    return false;
} else{
    //do stuff here
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use something like this :

```
var inputstate = false;

$('#tableItems').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest("td").hasClass("cssClick")) {

        if(!inputstate){
            inputstate = true;

            setTimeout((function(element){
                return function(){
                    UpdateItemStatus(element);
                    inputstate = false;
                };
            })(this),50);
        }
    }
});
```

the setTimeout used to "defer the call" of your UpdateItemStatus function.
Because if this listener is fired, (an other listener cannot be fired at the same time) the value of the boolean will change to the end state before that the next click will be handled

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `UpdateItemStatus()` uses some asynchronous call (ajax?), so here's how i would do it:

```
$('#tableItems').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    var $td = $(e.target).closest("td");
    if ($td.hasClass("cssClick")) {
        $td.toggleClass("cssClick");
        UpdateItemStatus(this.id).done(function(){
            $td.toggleClass("cssClick");                
        });
    }
});
```

and in UpdateItemStatus:

```
function UpdateItemStatus(id){
    //do stuff
    return $.ajax(...);
}
```